# How to select the max row for every group in spark structured streaming 2.3.0 using Raw Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark

How to select the max row for every group in spark structured streaming 2.3.0 without using `order by` or `mapGroupWithState`?

**Input:**

```
id | amount     | my_timestamp
-------------------------------------------
1  |      5     |  2018-04-01T01:00:00.000Z
1  |     10     |  2018-04-01T01:10:00.000Z
2  |     20     |  2018-04-01T01:20:00.000Z
2  |     30     |  2018-04-01T01:25:00.000Z
2  |     40     |  2018-04-01T01:30:00.000Z
```

**Expected Output:**

```
id | amount     | my_timestamp
-------------------------------------------
1  |     10     |  2018-04-01T01:10:00.000Z
2  |     40     |  2018-04-01T01:30:00.000Z
```

Looking for a streaming solution using either raw sql like `sparkSession.sql("sql query")` or similar to raw sql but not something like `mapGroupWithState`

Comment: You can use any aggregating method (not join or window function) in `complete` output mode.

Comment: @user6910411 I am not sure why you think this is a duplicate question since my question is all about streaming and it is not an easy one to solve. I don't see an easy or definite solution yet given the restrictions I specified in the question. If you think its easy please help

Comment: `order by` in complete mode just generates a lot of data and that is not what I am looking as I already specified in the question

Comment: I am wondering about performance in this case.

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: Do u agree it is a duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple approaches to solve this problem.

**Approach 1 :**

You can use Window operations in Spark

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{Window, WindowSpec}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, desc, rank}

val filterWindow: WindowSpec = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(desc("amount"))

val df = ???

df.withColumn("temp_rank", rank().over(filterWindow))
.filter(col("temp_rank") === 1)
.drop("temp_rank")
```

The problem with this is that it does not work with Structured Streaming as windowing is only supported on `TIMESTAMP` columns. **This works for batch jobs.**

**Approach 2:**

With the specified conditions in the question you could go with something like below. The grouping is done on `id` and the grouped contents are converted to `Seq[A]`. Here, `A` represents a `Struct`. This Seq is then filtered out for the record.

```
object StreamingDeDuplication {

  case class SubRecord(time: java.sql.Timestamp, amount: Double)

  val subSchema: StructType = new StructType().add("time", TimestampType).add("amount", DoubleType)

  def deDupe: UserDefinedFunction =
    udf((data: Seq[Row]) => data.maxBy(_.getAs[Double]("amount")), subSchema)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("StreamingDeDuplication").getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
    val records = spark.readStream
      .format("socket")
      .option("host", "localhost")
      .option("port", 9999)
      .load()
      .as[String]
      .map(_.split(","))
      .withColumn("id", $"value".getItem(0).cast("STRING"))
      .withColumn("amount", $"value".getItem(1).cast("DOUBLE"))
      .withColumn("time", $"value".getItem(2).cast("TIMESTAMP"))
      .drop("value")

    val results = records
      .withColumn("temp", struct("time", "amount"))
      .groupByKey(a => a.getAs[String]("id"))
      .agg(collect_list("temp").as[Seq[SubRecord]])
      .withColumnRenamed("collect_list(temp)", "temp_agg")
      .withColumn("af", deDupe($"temp_agg"))
      .withColumn("amount", col("af").getField("amount"))
      .withColumn("time", col("af").getField("time"))
      .drop("af", "temp_agg")

    results
      .writeStream
      .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
      .option("truncate", "false")
      .format("console")
      .start().awaitTermination()
  }

}
```

Comment: hi please read my question carefully. 1) is this a streaming solution or batch solution?. I am looking for a streaming solution 2) order by in streaming can only be done in complete mode which produces a lot of data so I try not to use order by.

Comment: I assume you are talking about batch since `over` is not supported in streaming

Comment: right, So I'm updating the answer with a solution that works on structured streaming as per the conditions you specified

Comment: thanks a lot for this. Is groupByKey allowed in raw sql ? like `sparkSession.sql("select * from table groupByKey...")`

Comment: Im not sure of the sql part, but it doesn't work IMO. do mark it as accepted if it helped. thanks

Comment: Does it work in fact as I note no tick and what about performance?

Comment: @thebluephantom not using raw sql which is the solution I am looking for

Comment: I have been curious on this topic and not able to resolve. But you did or did not resolve? If so intetested in source example. Not sure if state mgt reqd

Comment: did not resolve and it is not a duplicate since my question is related to raw spark sql.

Comment: Is it not possible to do that with Spark Structured Streaming?